# Controller specific assets with an admin namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller "organizations" that is available both as a normal resource, as well as namespaced under "admin".

I need to add some javascript that is only relevant to the organizations actions, and it applies to both the admin namespace and non-admin namespace. I read in the guides that I should create a file "organizations.js.coffee" and include something like this in my layout file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

The problem is that params[:controller] includes /admin for the admin namespace.

What is the proper way I should be doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A few points. Firstly, in this instance, this should work:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller].split('/').last %>
```

However, if you have that on every page, and one controller doesn't have a JS file, things will break, so you may instead want to do:

```
<% if params[:controller].split('/').last == "organization" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "organisation" %>
<% end %>
```

It's probably worth adding this as a helper method, e.g.:

```
module OrganizationHelper
  def organization_javascript
    javascript_include_tag "organization" if params[:controller].split('/').last == "organization"
  end
end

<%= organization_javascript %>
```

Also, in newer versions of Rails, you can use `controller_name` instead of `params[:controller]`

You might also want to consider just rendering the `organization.js` into your `application.js` (which will be done automatically in the assets pipeline in Rails 3.1 onwards). If it contains JS that users will probably hit during their visit, then it's probably worth doing to reduce the number of files that need to be downloaded.

Comment: this worked, but isn't there a way to put the asset stylesheets and javascripts in a sub folder?